# Making GWT 2.5 compiler use closure compiler

Tags: gwt, google-closure-compiler

The [release notes](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/ReleaseNotes) for GWT 2.5 say that the GWT compiler can optionally use the Closure compiler to provide additional JavaScript optimizations, does anyone know how to turn this optimization on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compile option is `-XenableClosureCompiler`. But I'm not sure if it already works with 2.5RC1.

Comment: it should but it has some limitations (the "story of your compile" report is disabled).

Comment: Hi, in eclipse, I would like to be sure that the option enableClosureCompiler is activated when I upload my app to production mode with GAE... So where should I put this option, I hesitate between : right CLick > Google > GWT compile  __or__ Run > Run configuration > Web application > Arguments ? Thank you.